# 'qgis: splitvectorlayer': wrong output directory

Tags: qgis, python

I have implemented the algorithm 'qgis: splitvectorlayer' in python and it works also, but the algorithm does not save the newly created shapefiles in the output directory, but in the input folder. Why?

```
import sys

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins')  # Folder where Processing is located
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

input = QgsVectorLayer('C:/OSGeo4W64/_StreetGeneratorDev/tryouts/files/centre/cir/streets.shp', 'test', 'ogr')
output = "C:/OSGeo4W64/_StreetGeneratorDev/tryouts/files/centre/cir/singlefiles/"
field = "angle"

general.runalg('qgis:splitvectorlayer', input, field, output)
```

Comment: Try an output filename  (with .shp) instead of just a folder name.

Comment: This didn't change anything. The algorithm create the output folder but generate the shapefiles in the input directory

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the "/" in your 'output' variable. A simple script such as this one worked for me with this algorithm:

```
import processing

input=iface.activeLayer()
output = 'C:\Temp'
field = 'Ball'
processing.runalg('qgis:splitvectorlayer', input, field, output)
```

Comment: It worked for me too, but the next time it don't work... Curious